# onChange method of ContentObserver not called when SMS message is read on Android

Tags: android

I was looking quite a bit on the forums for determining how many SMS messages I have that were not read. The code below seems to work good for received messages, but once I actually read the message the onChange of the ContentObserver is not being called.
So, on incoming SMS message the onChange is getting called and I get the correct number, but after reading the message **it is not being called**. The device is Samsung Note running Android 2.3.6 not rooted. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class UnreadSMSContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private static final String myTAG="PhoneInfoSMS";
    private static final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private Handler mHandler;
    public int unreadSMS;
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneInfoSMS";

    public UnreadSMSContentObserver(ContentResolver cr, Handler h) {
        super(null);
        mContentResolver = cr;
        mHandler = h;
    }

    public int getUnreadSMS() {
        if (mContentResolver != null) {
            try {
                Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
                if (c != null) {
                    unreadSMS = c.getCount(); 
                    c.deactivate();
                    Log.d(TAG, unreadSMS + " unread SMS messages");
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("ERROR: " + ex.toString(), "");
            }
        }
        return unreadSMS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(myTAG, "onChange");
        if (mContentResolver != null) {
            getUnreadSMS();
            mHandler.obtainMessage(PhoneInfoServer.CONTENTO_INFOCHANGED, PhoneInfoServer.CONTENTO_US, unreadSMS).sendToTarget();
            Log.d(myTAG, "done");
        }
    }
}
```

In the manifest file I have the following permissions:

```
"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
"android.permission.READ_SMS"
"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
"android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"
"android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
"android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
"android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
"android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
"android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
"android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
```

The way I set it up on the calling service is:
in the onCreate of the service I do:

```
mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
mUnreadSMSContentObserver = new UnreadSMSContentObserver(mContentResolver, mContentObserversHandler);
```

in the onStartCommand of the service I do:

```
mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true, mUnreadSMSContentObserver);               
mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/"), true, mUnreadSMSContentObserver);
```

I tried only the content://sms/ and only content://sms/inbox/ and both... did not solve the problem.

P.S. Similar method for the missed calls works perfect!

The application+service is sending over Bluetooth the battery data, missed calls and unread SMS messages to an Arduino based device that displays it on an LED screen. Why? Two reasons: first, this is my first Android program made for fun. The second is I am not carrying the phone with me at home all the time, and it is typically in my home office. If I did not hear it ringing I will still be able to see the LED display telling me I had calls or SMS when passing by.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling super(h), not super(null)?

Answer (score 1):

this solution has worked for me :

```
 context.getContentResolver().
                registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/"), true, smsObserver);
```